# Navigation controller with static table in container view

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, containers, swift

I've got a static table view as the main screen for my app right now, which is embedded in a container of the root view controller. the problem that i'm having is all of the items/pages that come from the original static table do not show a navigation bar in the storyboard. how to you recommend fixing this so I can use my UINavigationController in this container table. thank you.

Comment: What does "all of the items/pages that come from the original static table" mean? Are you going to other controllers from the embedded table view controller (rather than from the parent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenes in storyboard that do not come from a controller that has a navigation controller do not inherit the nav bar. To see what it looks like with a nav go to the scene in storyboard, then Attribute inspector from the right panel and change that controller to show a `top bar` instead of `Inherit`. This is useful when the code is adding the controller to the stack but there is no direct connection in storyboard from the controller to a navigation controller.
[image]

Now if your problem is that when you run the app app Segues from the static table push to controllers where there is no nav bar, this could be a result of embedding a tableViewController in a containerController. Maybe try setting a delegate on that `TableViewController` on the `didSelectRow` method and telling the Parent of the container to push.